# Why the WCF server's ip address discovered by WCF client can't be ping success？

Tags: c#, wcf

There are two roles in my software system, one is WCF server, another is WCF client. The WCF server is boradcasting the WCF server's ip address in the intranet. Launch the WCF client, the WCF client will discover all the WCF server in the intranet. The user can see all the WCF server ip addresses found by the WCF client. And the WCF client will connect to the WCF server which the user selected.
But I found a strange question. Sometimes the found WCF server ip address is different from the actual WCF server. 
**For example:**
The WCF server ip address is 192.168.1.66, and I can ping success as follow picture.
[IP address is 192.168.1.66](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj5OI.png)

But, the found ip address by WCF client is 192.168.66.1 as follow picutre.
[Found ip address is 192.168.66.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mErUW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The IP address in your second screen shot is 192.186.66.1, not 192.168.66.1.

My guess is that the server is multi-homed and 192.186.66.1 is its preferred IP address but it still responds to ICMP pings (and other traffic) on 192.168.1.66.

Comment: Yeah, the actual debug found ip address is 192.186.66.1, but this ip address can't be ping success. So strangely.

Comment: Probably firewalls. They'll probably be blocking ICMP for 192.186.66.0/24 (a public network, perhaps) and allowing ICMP for 192.168.66.0/24 (a private internal network).

Comment: Thank you, I found the reason，there has installed a VMware and enable the VMware in the WCF server computer. After disable the VMware, the found ip address by WCF client is became 192.168.1.66 (same as the acutal ip address).